# Use child theme on certain pages and not others?

Tags: child-theme

I have created a twenty-eleven child theme, I want to know if its possible to only load that child theme on certain pages, maybe with the custom page templates?

I have looked via google and on here and have found nothing on the twenty-eleven or very outdated posts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use page templates for that if you have a page template within your them, and if its a different theme all together then you can use [**Page Theme**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-theme/) which is a plugin that can be used to display a different **theme** (not template) for each page/post of your blog.

Comment: Great thanks, so how would I go about setting up and telling a custom page template to load the child theme files & css when that template is selected? Any links would be great, kind of a newbie to custom page templates, I did a search and what I find does not seem to relate to the new setup of the twenty-eleven theme.

Comment: From your comment i can tell that you got this whole thing wrong, you use either custom page template which is based on the current theme or the plugin i linked which lets you specify a theme per page

Comment: Gotcha thanks. Unfortunately that plugin doesnt seem to like child themes, guess I just have to make a theme and test it.